# Using the Excel VBA Selenium with Chrome, I am attempting to Click the 'Export to CSV' button

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I prefer using Xpath with the Class, but for some reason am not picking-up any hits on the Class identifiers shown within the image.

This is the full path to the Span text 'Export to CSV'...

- /html/body/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/a[1]/span

[image: html code/tagging image]

What am I missing?

Comment: In the Chrome Dev Tools window, you can right-click and [copy the full Xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sNmc.png) of the element. Does it match the Xpath you have in your question?

Comment: Here's what I have found so far.  The correct path and search seems to be: //div[@class='css-ie8gg5']/a[1][@class='css-1hlni58']/span[text()='Export To CSV'].  As performing a search within the html demonstrates that it is unique, as it is found and is 1 of 1.

Comment: So, problem solved?

Comment: @DecimalTurn, Thank you.  No, while I search and find the unique string in the HTML, XPath does not find it for some reason.

Comment: Hard to diagnose without your code and/or the full HTML on the page.

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  Unfortunately, working with a lot of business proprietary info that I cannot expose, hence the hieroglyphics.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Resolved.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear you've solved your issue! If there is information that you can share in an answer about how you solved the issue, I'd encourage you to do so. In case someone with the same problem finds this question, that would be really helpful. Otherwise, there wouldn't really be a reason to keep this question on the site.